# Infinispan with File Store with Replication enabled

Tags: infinispan

Can we have FileStore configuration and cluster (Replication) enabled in infini span cache? Could someone give sample configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The same content will be persisted on all nodes. When restarting some node, however, you should set the cache store to be purged, otherwise already removed entries could get loaded back to the cache.